# Display value of slider using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

How to display current Value of slider only while it's clicked? Something like tooltip but not on mouse-over.

This code gives me value of slider on mouse-over and it's shown as double value:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Maximum="100" Margin="76,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider}" Value="80"/>
```

How do I modify it to receive integer value and only when the slider it's clicked?

Comment: To display an integer, you could use a converter in your binding. To change the behaviour of your tooltip, your best and simplest bet would probalby be to try to style the said tooltip

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of explicitly setting a ToolTip, set the `AutoToolTipPlacement` and `AutoToolTipPrecision` properties, e.g.

```
<Slider ... AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft" AutoToolTipPrecision="0" />
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!